# How to pass string from function into decorator?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I want to take an input from a function:

```
def input_text():
    text = input('Type the text:\n')
    # deco_required = input('Format variable\n')
    return text
```

Then I want a decorator to format the text from the input above:

```
def center(input_text):
    def centering(*args,**kwargs):
        t = '<center>{}</center>' .format(kwargs)
        return input_text
    return centering
```

I thought this was the correct way to go about it:

```
@centring
input_text()
```

I get the following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-10-95c74b9f0757>", line 2
    input_text()
             ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

which is not very helpful for me to look up.

Comment: You decorate a function *definition*, not a *call*. If you want to apply the decorator to a function at call time, you need to do e.g. `center(input_text)()`. But note that also your decorator itself doesn't make sense, you get the input from invoking the wrapped function, *not* from the call to the wrapper.

Comment: You'll need to look over your code, there's misspelled function names ("centring") and extraneous spaces (before the `.format(kwargs)`. I also assume you want to return `t`, not `input_text` in `centering`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, without a decorator you would simply pass the return value of `input_text` to a centering function.

```
def centering(s):
    return '<center>{}</center>'.format(s)

centered_text = centering(input_text)
```

A function that does this for you might look like

```
def input_centered_text():
    text = input('Temp the text:')
    centered_text = centering(text)
    return centered_text
```

A decorator that can produce `input_centered_text` from the original `input_text` would look like

```
def center(f):
    def _():
        centered_text = f()
        return centered_text
    return _
```

and used like either

```
def input_text():
    text = input('Type the text:\n')
    return text


input_centered_text = center(input_text)
```

or

```
@center
def input_centered_text():  # Note the change in the function name
    text = input('Type the text:\n')
    return text
```

Comment: Thanks. The example that I gave was only for understanding the concept. I think I understand the concept way better now.